# water leaking into room downstairs when I shower

Tags: plumbing

Shower leaks into room below only when I shower, not my husband. He is 6 feet tall and I am 5 feet so must adjust shower head. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Do the two of you spend the same amount of time in the shower?

Comment: If you shower after him it could just be the delay in getting wet. Nevertheless any leak isn't good. It's either your drain or surround. If you have access to the the drain from below, it should be easier to pinpoint.

Comment: What if you both share it?  :-) (bad joke)

Comment: Consider that it may not be a plumbing leak, but a leaking tile joint.  I know of a case where the cause was the tub needed to be re-caulked.   One person didn't splash that wall so much with their showers (so it didn't appear to leak) another person basically directed the shower stream more against that wall and caused a waterfall.